# Scanning and indexing files video

Tags: java, android

I use the following method to scan and index video files and pass data to an array. I get video file duration, file name, files size.

Is there any better method, or do I need to improve?

```
public static void load_Directory_Files(File directory) {
    File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
    if(fileList != null && fileList.length > 0){
        for (int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++){
            if(fileList[i].isDirectory()){
                load_Directory_Files(fileList[i]);
            } else {
                String name = fileList[i].getName().toLowerCase();
                for (String extension: Constant.videoExtensions){
                    //check the type of file
                    if(name.endsWith(extension)){
                        Constant.allMediaList.add(fileList[i]);
                        String FileName = fileList[i].getName();
                        String size = Function.humanReadableByteCountSI(fileList[i].length());
                        String duration = Function.getDurationFF(fileList[i].getAbsolutePath());
                        String folderName = fileList[i].getParentFile().getName();
                        String path = fileList[i].getAbsolutePath();
                        Log.d(TAG, "load_Directory_Files: "+ duration + "" +size + "" + FileName);
                        Constant.allMediaListWithModel.add(new AllVideoModel(FileName, path, folderName, size, duration));
                        //when we found file
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



public static String getDurationFF(String absolutePathThumb) {
    try{
        FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(absolutePathThumb);
        String time = retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time);
        return convertMillieToHMmSs(timeInMillisec);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public static String convertMillieToHMmSs(long millie) {
    long seconds = (millie / 1000);
    long second = seconds % 60;
    long minute = (seconds / 60) % 60;
    long hour = (seconds / (60 * 60)) % 24;
    if (hour > 0) {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
    } else {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d" , minute, second);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public static String humanReadableByteCountSI(long bytes) {
    if (-1000 < bytes && bytes < 1000) {
        return bytes + " B";
    }
    CharacterIterator ci = new StringCharacterIterator("kMGTPE");
    while (bytes <= -999_950 || bytes >= 999_950) {
        bytes /= 1000;
        ci.next();
    }
    return String.format("%.1f %cB", bytes / 1000.0, ci.current());
}
```

The above method works but it takes time to scan and index. So how can I reduce indexing time?

```
public static String[] videoExtensions = {".mp4",".ts",".mkv",".mov",
        ".3gp",".mv2",".m4v",".webm",".mpeg1",".mpeg2",".mts",".ogm",
        ".bup", ".dv",".flv",".m1v",".m2ts",".mpeg4",".vlc",".3g2",
        ".avi",".mpeg",".mpg",".wmv",".asf"};
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [*what you may and may not do after receiving answers*](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 4):

## Naming

The method name `load_Directory_Files` is a bit odd. To follow general Java naming conventions, it would be something like `loadDirectoryFiles`. This is called camel case.

## File filtering

You can use a [`FileFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileFilter) to accept or discard files for the
[`listFiles`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)) call, no need to do it yourself:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class VideoOrDirectoryFilter implements FileFilter {

    private static final List<String> ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = Arrays.asList(
        ".mp4",".ts",".mkv",".mov",".3gp",".mv2",".m4v",".webm",
        ".mpeg1",".mpeg2",".mts",".ogm", ".bup", ".dv",".flv",
        ".m1v",".m2ts",".mpeg4",".vlc",".3g2",".avi",".mpeg",
        ".mpg",".wmv",".asf"
    );

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory() 
            || ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS.contains(file.getName().toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

## Null check

In `loadDirectoryFiles`, you can return early if the `listFiles` call is null:

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles(new VideoOrDirectoryFilter());
if (files == null) return;
```

## Looping

Instead of the for loop with an index variable, you could use a [`foreach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) loop. That makes for cleaner code, as you directly get the object in the list. Also, you don't need to check the length of the list before looping. If it's empty, the loop will be a no-op.

```
for (File file : files) {
    // Do your thing with file here
}
```

## Reimplementation

Here's a reimplementation of the `loadDirectoryFiles` method with the above enhancements included.

```
public static void loadDirectoryFiles(File directory) {
    File[] files = directory.listFiles(new VideoOrDirectoryFilter());

    if (files == null) return;

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()){
            loadDirectoryFiles(file);
        } else {            
            Constant.allMediaList.add(file);
            String fileName = file.getName();
            String size = Function.humanReadableByteCountSI(file.length());
            String duration = Function.getDurationFF(file.getAbsolutePath());
            String folderName = file.getParentFile().getName();
            String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d(TAG, "load_Directory_Files: "+ duration + "" +size + "" + fileName);
            Constant.allMediaListWithModel.add(new AllVideoModel(fileName, path, folderName, size, duration));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite good. The only thing I'd suggest changing is `"load_Directory_Files: "+ duration + "" +size + "" + fileName` - that should just be a `format` call.

Comment: i tried but but no files are listed, here is how i implement https://gist.github.com/sanoj26692/5e5e9baedf0d3821213042581d248fc4

Comment: Can you make a github. Bcoz I tried ur code and that doesn't index any files